# Erro ao utlizar GetOldTweets3 com filtro para uma um determinado período

Tags: python

Olá, estou me aprimorando nos estudos em Python e deparei com o erro: IndexError: list index out of range

o Código que estou rodando é esse:

```
import GetOldTweets3 as got
max_tweets = 3
tweets=[]
tweetCriteria = got.manager.TweetCriteria().setUsername("@cbv_jlle").setSince("2019-03-29").setUntil("2019-03-31").setMaxTweets(max_tweets)
for i in range(max_tweets):
    tweet = got.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweetCriteria)[i]
    tweets.append(tweet.text)  

print(tweets)
```

Abaixo o erro:

```
> IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-85-287bf080b649> in <module>()
>       5 tweetCriteria = got.manager.TweetCriteria().setUsername("@cbv_jlle").setSince("2019-03-01").setUntil("2019-03-02").setMaxTweets(max_tweets)
>       6 for i in range(max_tweets):
> ----> 7     tweet = got.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweetCriteria)[i]
>       8     tweets.append(tweet.text)
>       9 print(tweets)
> 
> IndexError: list index out of range
```

**Algumas datas funcionam, outras não. Por exemplo se eu altero o intervalo para  `setSince("2019-03-29").setUntil("2019-03-31")` ele funciona.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TL;DR](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/getoldtweets3)

O que está a contecendo é que dependendo do período a linha `tweet = got.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweetCriteria)` está trazendo um numero de `tweets` maior do que o que vc definiu para `max_tweets` e seu erro foi colocar essa variável para determinar o número de iterações para o loop `for`, quando o número na variável `max_tweets` é maior do que a lista dos mesmos vc acaba tentando acessar algo inacessível no objeto.

Um outro equivoco pode pode ser observado no seu código, essa mesma linha (citada a cima) tende a deixa-lo extremamente lento, pois a cada passagem toda a leitura é feita novamente pelo `getTweets(tweetCriteria)`, fiz algumas alteracoes, tente rodar dessa forma:

```
import GetOldTweets3 as got

max_tweets = 3
tweets=[]
tweetCriteria = got.manager.TweetCriteria().setUsername("@cbv_jlle").setSince("2019-03-29").setUntil("2019-03-31").setMaxTweets(max_tweets)

# A leitura dos tweets é feita uma vez só
twts = got.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweetCriteria)

for i in range(len(twts)):
    tweet = twts[i]
    tweets.append(tweet.text)
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/getoldtweets3)

Comment: Sidon, melhorou muito a performace!  Mas mesmo eu aumentando o meu max_tweets para maior que 100 (por exemplo), ele não retorna nada para o intervalo setSince("2019-03-01").setUntil("2019-03-02"). E pelo que vi na fonte (Bombeiros Joinville
@cbv_jlle) , deve ter uns 50 tweets no total para os 2 dias. Será que tem a ver com o tamanho das mensagens, pois tem umas mensagens que são um pouco mais extensas?

Comment: Estranho, fiz u m teste aqui e retorna 25 tweets nesse periodo, estou colocando no repl.it, vou editar a minha resposta e colocar o link lá.

Comment: Ok, o link já esta na resposta vá lá e "brinque" um pouco, mude o numero da variável `max_tweets` e das variáveis que determinam o período `d1` e `d2`.

Comment: Show de bola!!! Não conhecia o repl.it!! Muito obrigada pela ajuda!!!